# How to select next instance of selected text in Webstorm?

Tags: text-editors, ide, webstorm

[image]

I can't find what the shortcut is to jump to the next selected word in Webstorm.

In Sublime text for instance, if I selected `selectTicker` all I have to do is click <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and I will jump to the next instance of that selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> (for OS X <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>)

For more details check official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d1743632e270).